# How to change all my account endpoints urls in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, account

I'm using Woocommerce Version 4.8.0 I have a problem with my account page
I want to change all the URLs like the image down below:

[image: URLs]

I have found on stackoverflow the solution for it but the code  change only one URL not all of them

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'woocommerce_hacks_endpoint_url_filter', 10, 4);
function woocommerce_hacks_endpoint_url_filter($url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink) {
    $downloads = get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_downloads_endpoint', 'downloads');
    if (empty($downloads) == false) {
        if ($endpoint == $downloads) {
            $url = '//example.com/customer-area/dashboard';
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All related endpoints slugs can be found on WooCommerce settings > Advanced *(tab)* >  Account endpoints:

[image]

Then you can use a switch statement to change the required account endpoints URLs as follows:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'change_my_account_endpoint_urls', 10, 4);
function change_my_account_endpoint_urls( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ) {
    switch($endpoint){
        case 'orders':
            $url = home_url('/customer-area/the-orders/');
            break;
        case 'downloads':
            $url = home_url('/customer-area/the-downloads/');
            break;
        case 'edit-address':
            $url = home_url('/customer-area/the-edit-address/');
            break;
        case 'edit-account':
            $url = home_url('/customer-area/new-edit-account/');
            break;
        case 'payment-methods':
            $url = home_url('/customer-area/the-payment-methods/');
            break;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> To change the My account URL itself, you need to edit the my account page in backend and change its permalink (editing the URL slug).